# springboot whitelabel error page, what to do?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am new to `SpringBoot` and I have written my first program, but I get `Whitelabel Error Page` all the time. I have already the other solutions provided, for example, to move my main class to the main package folder. But it didn't help me. Here you can see the structure of my project:
[image]

How can I change the structure? I have tried to make a package on top of the other packages to move the main class to, but it didn't work. Actually, I can't make nested packages now, and sometimes I see that after adding a new class/package, the structure of the project is automatically changed!!
I also tried to move the main class to the same package as the controllers, but it also didn't work. I even tried ComponentScan() but I got some new errors with this approach. Can anyone please explain me, what I have done wrongly and how I can get rid of this problem?

Update: CarController:

```
import com.tests4geeks.tutorials.model.Car;
import com.tests4geeks.tutorials.repository.CarMongoRepository;
import com.tests4geeks.tutorials.repository.CarSearchRepository;

@EnableAutoConfiguration

@Controller

public class CarController {

@Autowired
CarMongoRepository carRepository;

@Autowired
CarSearchRepository carSearchRepository;

@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("carList", carRepository.findAll());
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addCar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCar(@ModelAttribute Car car) {
    carRepository.save(car);
    return "redirect:home";
}

  @RequestMapping(value = "/search")
    public String search(Model pModel, @RequestParam String search) {//         pModel.addAttribute("carList", searchRepository.searchCars(search));
pModel.addAttribute("search", search); return "home";
    }

}
```

Best,

Comment: Why not including CarController huh?

Comment: @Antoniossss what do you mean by including? Including to the same package as the main class? I have tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I mean show me that gd code.....

Comment: @Antoniossss sorry, see updated version

Comment: And what URL are you trying to HIT ?

Comment: @Antoniossss http://localhost:8080/home

Comment: Upload to Github and share link, somebody will get it running in no time

Comment: check logs when you get the error, it should suggest what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

In your application class( HelloWorldSpringBootApp.java), **@SpringBootApplication** annotation is missing. I believe you have the import but not the annotation. Adding that should resolve the whitelabel error page issue. You can also add the @ComponentScan in your application class but the @SpringBootApplication takes care of that implicitly

You can read more about the annotation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

You can also disable and customize the whitelabel error page: https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-whitelabel-error-page/